# I want to show different icon for in asp:repeater

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have four different records all of the records are show perfectly but i have only one problem icon is same for each of the record i just want to change the icon for each record my code is as follow.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSourceID="dsservices">
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="item ">
        <div class="icon"><i style="line-height: 2;" class="fa fa-bed"></i></div>
        <h5><%#Eval("GenServiceTitle") %></h5>
        <p><%#Eval("GenServiceDes") %></p>
        <a href="#">more..</a>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: You can use Repeater.ItemDataBound Event for this refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You can bound your icon property with some dynamic values. Like the way you have done for "GenServiceTitle" and "GenServiceDes"

Comment: I have done it by using conditional statement in class using eval but i think that is not the best approach although it solve my problem.